# Knockout style binding not letting me append !important

Tags: knockout.js, data-binding

I'm trying to bind a background to a table cell like this:

```
data-bind="style: { background: Css }
```

Css variable can either equals a color like #F7C7D4.

This part works, and the cells are filled with the color, but when I try and print the page none of the colors show.  When I try this without the binding, like this:

```
<td style="background #F7C7D4 !important;"></td>
```

the color shows up on the page and when printing.  But when I change the code to:

```
data-bind="style: { background: Css + ' !important' }
```

knockout will not data bind the background.  Doesn't throw a error, but no color shows on the screen and when I inspect the element the background style hasn't been added to the style attribute.  I've also tried changing the Css variable to include the !important with the same results that the binding doesn't work.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shiftnote/qcqaxm3x/)

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`!important` isn't supported by the style binding. One option would be to use the `css` binding instead and using actual css classes.

Another options would be to use a custom binding. This is how the style binding applies a style as of Knockout 3.3.

```
ko.bindingHandlers['style'] = {
    'update': function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor() || {});
        ko.utils.objectForEach(value, function(styleName, styleValue) {
            styleValue = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(styleValue);

            if (styleValue === null || styleValue === undefined || styleValue === false) {
                // Empty string removes the value, whereas null/undefined have no effect
                styleValue = "";
            }

            element.style[styleName] = styleValue;
        });
    }
};
```

The key part being `element.style[styleName] = styleValue;`.

This method of setting a style doesn't support `!important`. Using `setProperty` instead will allow you to make it "important" but note that this only works on IE9+.

```
element.style.setProperty('background', '#F7C7D4', 'important');
```

Here's an example of what that binding might look like.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.myCustomStyleBinding = {
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor() || {});
        ko.utils.objectForEach(value, function(styleName, styleValue) {
            var isImportant = false;
            styleValue = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(styleValue);

            if (styleValue === null || styleValue === undefined || styleValue === false) {
                // Empty string removes the value, whereas null/undefined have no effect
                styleValue = "";
            }

            isImportant = styleValue.indexOf('!important') > -1;
            styleValue = styleValue.split(' !important')[0];
            element.style.setProperty(styleName, styleValue, isImportant ? 'important' : '');
        });
    }
};
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use `attr` binding to set the value of style attribute)

```
data-bind="attr:{ style: 'background: ' + Css() + ' !important' }
```

Comment: Somehow, this doesn't work if there are more than 1 properties. Like adding color as well along with background. In such cases, it gives an error of `Unexpected token '+'`.